# Group By Expression But Get the Specific Record

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

this is my query

```
SELECT TBL.PREFIX,
             TBL.BASE,
             TBL.SUFFIX,
             TBL.CONTROL,
             LISTAGG (TBL.QT_PART_USAGE, ',')    AS QT_PART_USAGE,
             LISTAGG (TBL.ADDORDELETE, ',')      AS COMESFROM,
             CASE
                 WHEN COUNT (*) > 1 THEN 'QT'
                 ELSE LISTAGG (TBL.ADDORDELETE, ',')
             END                                 AS ADDORDELETE
        FROM TBL
    GROUP BY TBL.CONTROL,
             TBL.PREFIX,
             TBL.BASE,
             TBL.SUFFIX
```

in TBL, I use a complicated select query but it's not so important so I represent it as 'TBL'

this query returns something like that:
[image: query returns]

[image: query returns continue]

all I want to do is:
if 'ADDORDELETE' = 'QT'

then I want to get the QT_PART_USAGE from the record 'COMESFROM' = 'ADD' **respectively**

example:

**QT_PART_USAGE    -     COMESFROM         -ADDORDELETE**

7,9               -ADD,DELETE   -QT

I want to get

**QT_PART_USAGE        - COMESFROM         -ADDORDELETE**

7                     -'WHATEVER'        -QT

or

**QT_PART_USAGE        - COMESFROM         -ADDORDELETE**

1,3               -DELETE,ADD   -QT

I want to get

**QT_PART_USAGE         -COMESFROM         -ADDORDELETE**

3                     -'WHATEVER'        -QT

depending on the sequence of the ADD in the COMESFROM column,

(DELETE,ADD) (1,3) then QT_PART_USAGE = 3

(ADD,DELETE) (7,9) then QT_PART_USAGE = 7

I want to get the QT_PART_USAGE value respect to it's index in the COMESFROM column.

May you guys help me? I appreciate a lot, thank you.

I tried getting the value with splitting the COMESFROM with ',' and get the index of the 'ADD' then respect to this index I tried to get the value from QT_PART_USAGE column but I know it's not optimal solution and so challenging. Also inner select queries make the query slow so I want to ask it here.

Comment: I don't use Oracle but after a little research, seems this needs IF THEN ELSE, SUBSTRING, INSTR. Edit question to show your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like here:

```sql
Select  
    QT_PART_USAGE "QT_PART_USAGE",
    --
    CASE WHEN ADDORDELETE != 'QT' THEN QT_PART_USAGE
    ELSE
        CASE  WHEN InStr(COMES_FROM, 'ADD', 1, 1) = 1 THEN SubStr(QT_PART_USAGE, 1, InStr(QT_PART_USAGE, ',', 1, 1) -1 )
              WHEN InStr(COMES_FROM, 'ADD', 1, 1) > 1 THEN SubStr(QT_PART_USAGE, InStr(QT_PART_USAGE, ',', 1, 1) + 1 )
        END
    END "QT_PART_USAGE_CHANGED",
    COMES_FROM "COMES_FROM",
    ADDORDELETE "ADDORDELETE"
From
    sample_data
```

I left your original QT_PART_USAGE colum intact and created a new, CHANGED one, so you can see them both. With your sample data:

```sql
WITH
    sample_data AS
        (
            Select '1'            "QT_PART_USAGE",  'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '1'            "QT_PART_USAGE",  'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '1'            "QT_PART_USAGE",  'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '.00025,1'     "QT_PART_USAGE",  'DELETE,ADD'      "COMES_FROM",   'QT'        "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All 
            Select '2'            "QT_PART_USAGE",  'DELETE'          "COMES_FROM",   'DELETE'  "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '2'            "QT_PART_USAGE",  'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            --
            Select '3'           "QT_PART_USAGE",   'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '1'           "QT_PART_USAGE",   'DELETE'          "COMES_FROM",   'DELETE'  "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '7,9'         "QT_PART_USAGE",   'ADD,DELETE'      "COMES_FROM",   'QT'        "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '1'           "QT_PART_USAGE",   'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '1'           "QT_PART_USAGE",   'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual Union All
            Select '2'           "QT_PART_USAGE",   'ADD'             "COMES_FROM",   'ADD'       "ADDORDELETE" From Dual 
        )
```

... it should return this ...

```sql
QT_PART_USAGE QT_PART_USAGE_CHANGED COMES_FROM ADDORDELETE
------------- --------------------- ---------- -----------
1                                   ADD        ADD         
1                                   ADD        ADD         
1                                   ADD        ADD         
.00025,1      1                     DELETE,ADD QT          
2                                   DELETE     DELETE      
2                                   ADD        ADD         
3                                   ADD        ADD         
1                                   DELETE     DELETE      
7,9           7                     ADD,DELETE QT          
1                                   ADD        ADD         
1                                   ADD        ADD         
2                                   ADD        ADD
```

*NOTE*: This will not work if there are three or more elements. Also, if there could be spaces within the string (QT_PART_USAGE) you should get ridd of them before getting substrings...